# Error: Could not import "file_name" in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, error-handling

I am trying to make a basic project in Flask, and I get this error when doing this:

[image]

```
Error: Could not import "file_name" in flask
```

Here is the code I was trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/")

def hello():
    return "My website"
```

Please ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: Also, the "flaskfirstthingpythonputthisname" is the name of the file. Sorry about putting such an idiotic name, but I was out of name ideas.

Comment: Posting screenshots is generally not ideal in questions, could you please reformat it with the contents of the screenshot in a code block.

Comment: hi maybe you problem is because you are on the wrong folder, move one folder forward , and not use the dot py at the end of

Comment: @JaimeAndresValenciaGaviria This question is already solved. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "My website"


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

FYI: Sharing screenshots is a bad idea: the error isn't clearly visible, and few would bother opening another tab to see the logs, when it really should be clearly shown and formatted in your question itself.